# Why the Unity animation doesn't work on the horizontal side?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I used unity to develop a 2D game. And I used the EasyTouch package. When using the keycode for go left and right, the animation is triggered by setting the `flag = 3` for the left side and `flag = 4` for the right side. However, if I used joystick instead, both left and right side animations did not work. Could someone help me solve this problem? Thanks a lot.

```
void Movement()
{   
    if(joystick.JoystickAxis.x<0)
    {

    //if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")<0) {
        anim.SetInteger("flag",3);
        transform.Translate(Vector3.left*speed*Time.deltaTime);

    }

    if(joystick.JoystickAxis.x>0)
    {
        //if(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")>0) {
        anim.SetInteger("flag",4);
        transform.Translate (Vector3.right*speed*Time.deltaTime);
    }

    if(joystick.JoystickAxis.y<0)
    {
         anim.SetInteger("flag",1);
         //if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")<0) {
         transform.Translate (Vector3.down*speed*Time.deltaTime);

    }

    if(joystick.JoystickAxis.y>0)
    {
        anim.SetInteger("flag",2);
        //if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")>0) {
        transform.Translate (Vector3.up*speed*Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") method for your script. But for this you have to change your project input settings. TO do this Follow these steps:

- Go to **Edit**->**Project Settings**->**Input**
- Under **Inspector Menu** you will find **Axes** List.
- There is an option **Horizontal** under **Axes**.
- Under **Horizontal** there is a drop down for **Type**.
- Select **JoyStick Axis**
- Next to **Type** there is **Axis**. Select **X axis**.

Now try to test your script like this.

```
if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")<0) {
    anim.SetInteger("flag",3);
    transform.Translate(Vector3.left*speed*Time.deltaTime);

}
```

You can ask for any further help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally ,I found that answer:Because I put the Movement() function in Update(). That means every time I used the joystick, it will update the animation. So, the horizontal animation always be replaced by the vertical animation. 
Here is the modified version:
    void Movement()
    {
        if(joystick.JoystickAxis.x<-Mathf.Abs(joystick.JoystickAxis.y)){
            anim.SetInteger("flag",3);
            transform.Translate(Vector3.left*speed*Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if(joystick.JoystickAxis.x>Mathf.Abs(joystick.JoystickAxis.y)){
            anim.SetInteger("flag",4);
            transform.Translate (Vector3.right*speed*Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if(joystick.JoystickAxis.y<-Mathf.Abs(joystick.JoystickAxis.x)){
            anim.SetInteger("flag",1);
            transform.Translate (Vector3.down*speed*Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if(joystick.JoystickAxis.y>Mathf.Abs(joystick.JoystickAxis.x)){
            anim.SetInteger("flag",2);
            transform.Translate (Vector3.up*speed*Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }